# Animate List Item content on long press listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have a fragment with ListView. I want to implement standard android behavior - short click on list item - segue to next screen, on long press, otherwise - edit mode. I've managed to intercept long press event. 
From default state :

[image]

I want animatedly move picture and text right:

[image]

My list view item have the following layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/items_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/items_count"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int pos, long id) {
                //here either set animation on view v 
                // or call findViewById() and get ImageView/TextView and set animation on it
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, i've managed to intercept long press in ListView. My problem is - animation. I have a model file .java of .xml layout. I should findByID xml elements in model file and apply animation to them?